# Extraer imagen de un JPanel

Tags: java

Buenos días,
Tengo un problema, y es que no se como sacar la imagen de un jpanel y transformarlo a un objeto Image, he intentado con el siguiente código:

```
 private static BufferedImage createImage(JPanel panel) {
    int w = panel.getWidth();
    int h = panel.getHeight();
    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g = bi.createGraphics();
    panel.print(g);
    return bi;
 }
```

Pero claro ahor no se como convertir de BufferedImage a Image. Alguien me puede echar una mano, me sería de gran ayuda.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta lo siguiente, para convertir tu `BufferedImage` a imagen.

```
File salida= new File("imagen.png");
ImageIO.write(bi , "png", salida);
```

Comment: Ya esta ya lo he solucionado, al final era conforme explicas en tu respuesta, lo que yo he añadido más código por que me hacia falta para realizar una serie de operaciones, para que se mostrara conforme se deseaba. Gracias de todos modos